# Unity3d plugin is written in c#, I'd like to interact with it using UnityScript

Tags: c#, plugins, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I made a little android game in unity. I used UnityScript.

Most of the unity plugins I've come across are written in mostly in c#; this one, for example: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity. I can make simple changes (commenting out stuff), but for the most part I can't tell the difference between c# and the potholes on my street. This has limited me to the default setting of a very basic advertising plugin.

If it's possible, I'd like to make whatever calls I need to from a UnityScript, but I haven't been able to figure that out on my own.

Failing this, I'd need to get a good starting point for learning c#, in the context of unity3D development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take Unity3D's file compilation order into account, which is well documented at [Special Folders and Script Compilation Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html)

> This is significant in cases where a script must refer to classes
>   defined in other scripts. The basic rule is that anything that will be
>   compiled in a phase after the current one cannot be referenced.
>   Anything that is compiled in the current phase or an earlier phase is
>   fully available.

and

> A common example is where a UnityScript file needs to reference a
>   class defined in a C# file. You can achieve this by placing the C#
>   file inside a Plugins folder and the UnityScript file in a non-special
>   folder. If you don't do this, you will get an error saying the C#
>   class cannot be found.